# KeyNotFound(CodinkgKeys) when Fetching API SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to fetch two APIs in SwiftUI, the first Api works great, but when I try to fetch the second one I only get coding keys error.

first API is: "https://playground.devskills.co/api/rest/meal-roulette-app/meals"

Here is the code that dosent work:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct RecipeView: View {
    @State var recipeId: Int
    @State var data = SpecificMealData(
        specificMealRoulette:
            SpecificMealRoulette(
                id: 0,
                title: "Default Title",
                picture: "Default Image",
                description: "Default Description",
                Ingredients: "Default Ingredients"))
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.specificMealRoulette.title)
        }.onAppear{
            getData(id: recipeId)
        }
    }
    
    
    func getData(id: Int) {
        print("TAG Entered ID I FUNC")
        let urlString = "https://playground.devskills.co/api/rest/meal-roulette-app/meals/\(4)"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, _ , error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(SpecificMealData.self, from: data)
                        self.data = decodedData
                    } catch {
                        print("TAG Error!", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

//This is another file/class/struct

```
    import Foundation

struct MealsData: Decodable {
    var mealRoulette: [MealRoulette]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mealRoulette = "meal_roulette_app_meals"
    }
}

struct MealRoulette: Decodable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var picture: String
}

struct SpecificMealData: Decodable {
    var specificMealRoulette: SpecificMealRoulette
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case specificMealRoulette = "meal_roulette_app_meals_by_pk"
    }
    
}

struct SpecificMealRoulette: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var picture: String
    var description: String
    var Ingredients: String
}
```

this is the API I want to fetch:
[image]

```
    {
    "meal_roulette_app_meals_by_pk": {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Thai fried prawn & pineapple rice",
        "picture": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/devskills-prod.appspot.com/o/Thai%20fried%20prawn%20%26%20pineapple%20rice.webp?alt=media&token=268c55fc-e977-496c-be36-b99d9e6eba04",
        "description": "This quick, low calorie supper is perfect for a busy weeknight. Cook your rice in advance to get ahead - run it under cold water to chill quickly, then freeze in a food bag for up to one month.",
        "ingredients": "2 tsp sunflower oil,\nbunch spring onions  greens and whites separated both sliced,\n1 green pepper  deseeded and chopped into small chunks,\n140g pineapple  chopped into bite-sized chunks,\n3 tbsp Thai green curry paste,\n4 tsp light soy sauce  plus extra to serve,\n300g cooked basmati rice (brown white or a mix - about 140g uncooked rice),\n2 large eggs  beaten,\n140g frozen peas,\n225g can bamboo shoots  drained,\n250g frozen prawns  cooked or raw,\n2-3 limes  1 juiced the rest cut into wedges to serve,\nhandful coriander leaves (optional)"
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

Error! keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Ingredients", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "meal_roulette_app_meals_by_pk", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "Ingredients", intValue: nil) ("Ingredients").", underlyingError: nil))

Please be nice, this is my first time working with APIs in SwiftUI :)

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not images. Text can be searched and copied into an editor/IDE but not images.

Comment: Regarding the error, are you sure that it is Ingredients with a capital I? You should include a sample of the json as well.

Comment: Use small i in Ingredients and it will solve your problem. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I edited the post, I added the code and the api, thank you!!

Comment: Hi there - I'm glad you found a solution. Please could you edit your question to remove the parts that eventually turned out to be not relevant to what was going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model to this

```
struct SpecificMealRoulette: Decodable {
     var id: Int
     var title: String
     var picture: String
     var description: String
     var ingredients: String
}
```